# How can I develop an algorithm to schedule production?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, optimization

Given an an table that contains products I am selling with the dates, and given a table that contains the possible work orders with each work order, arrange the work orders such that all items are filled. (assume a starting stock of 0)

What I can produce per day:

| Item1 | 30 |
| --- | --- |
| Item2 | 20 |
| Item3 | 25 |

Sales Orders:

| Item | Day | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 1/1/2021 | 40 |
| Item2 | 1/1/2021 | 15 |
| Item3 | 1/2/2021 | 20 |
| Item2 | 1/5/2021 | 18 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Item2 | 12/31/2021 | 14 |

The efficiency of the solution can be judged by the standard deviation of the stock quantity.

For example if I have 100 of Item1 and 0 of Item2 the solution is inefficient. If I have 50 of each the solution is optimal.

I can't think of a way to calculate it other than to iterate through all possible configurations, leaving me with a runtime on $n!$

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in my question. Since order does not matter the complexity is simply $n\cdot m$ where $n$ is the amount of days and $m$ is the amount of items. Since this drastically reduces the complexity I consider this an answer. I will leave this open if others can provide an optimization.

Comment: (To keep *computational* complexity low, I guess I'd try sorting into ascending weighted sum and checking if that doesn't suffice. OTOH, `standard deviation of the stock quantity` is an alienating measure of quality. I'd go for minimal shipment delay, minimal (goods) storage, no outstanding shipments on Sylvester.)